# Laravel hasOne()->orderBy() vs hasOne()->ofMany()

Tags: laravel, eloquent, has-one

One bit of "magic" in the Laravel codebase is here in [HasOneOrMany.php](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/246873e3e1bb2ef9f3389f357242fd16ab83075e/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Relations/HasOneOrMany.php#L171) where if the underlying query behind a `hasOne` relationship technically fetches multiple rows, it will just return the first row instead.

```php
protected function getRelationValue(array $dictionary, $key, $type)
{
    $value = $dictionary[$key];
    return $type === 'one' ? reset($value) : $this->related->newCollection($value);
}
```

This got me thinking that, given a related model that is normally `hasMany`, an [`oldestOfMany()`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#has-one-of-many) relation can be simulated with just an `orderBy`, e.g.

```php
public function models() 
{
    return $this->hasMany(Model::class);
} 

public function firstModel() 
{
    return $this->hasOne(Model::class)->orderBy('created_at');
}
```

Are there any downsides to this shortcut approach?

---

As pointed out in the comments, calling `->first()` on the many relationship works just fine for actually retrieving a model.  In our app it's common to build relations from other relations, and I want to do that here.  e.g.

```php
public function firstActiveModel()
{
    return $this->firstModel()->active();
}
```

Comment: It's been a while since I used Laravel, but what's wrong with `$myObject->models()->first()` - is it not the same thing and more clearer?

Comment: I want a base relation that can then be chained with other constraints.  For actually retrieving the model, yes `first()` on the many relation would work just fine.

Comment: Again, it's been a while, but can you not just use `limit(1)` (or is it `take`? I can't remember). I'm pretty sure that returns a Builder instance that can be chained from.